# Can't solve NaN error (javascript)

Tags: javascript, calculator, nan

So I made this very basic form with just 4 inputs fields and a submit button with the value and onclick function "calculate".

Then I started coding some javascript for it that looks like this:

```
function calculate(){
var insert1 = document.getElementById('insert1').value;
var insert2 = document.getElementById('insert2').value;
var insert3 = document.getElementById('insert3').value;
var isnert4 = document.getElementById('insert4').value;

var results = insert1 * insert2 * insert3 * insert4;
document.write(results);
}
```

So I tested the code by pressing on the submit button and it only displayed "NaN". I noticed that when I change the parameter of the document.write to one of the inserts I don't get the error and it will display the value of the insert. So i think that the issues is in the var result line but i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Maybe try [debugging your code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: You need to provide a real [mcve]. The code you have given will throw a referenceerror, not display NaN (so you haven't verified it). A *complete* example would need to include the HTML and the data you were testing.

Comment: Ahhhh, it won't throw a referenceerror because `insert4` et al are globals implicitly created by the input elements. (That would have been more obvious if the [mcve] was complete)

Comment: there is a small typo at `var insert4` you wrote typed `var isnert4` thats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting a `NaN` is because attempting to multiply *anything* with `NaN` yields another `NaN`.

Due to a typo in your code:

```
var isnert4 = document.getElementById('insert4').value; 
     ^ --- here
```

But attempting to use the variable you intended:

```
var results = insert1 * insert2 * insert3 * insert4;
                              here ------------^
```

Means `insert4` is `NaN` and thus the result of the entire calculation is also `NaN`.

Correct the typo and your code will work as expected.

<sub>ps. Its 2017, stop using `document.write`!</sub>